# Does PlayFramework follow the front controller pattern?

Tags: playframework

Am I correct to think that the Playframework follows the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) because all the requests enter the same point and routed from there? You know the 
one that we define at`conf/routes` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that.

> You know the one that we define at `conf/routes` file.

That router can be programmed directly: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaSirdRouter

And replace the `one that we define at`conf/routes`file`: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaCompileTimeDependencyInjection#Application-entry-point

You can even combine them (Still there is only one "entry point"): https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaSirdRouter#Binding-sird-Router

And the "Command" from the "Front controller pattern" is exactly "Action" in the Play: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaActions

So yes, Play looks exactly like it follows the "Front controller pattern". To my mind, this pattern is so common, so I am not sure if Play creators follow it specially, like read that pattern description and build it according to pattern "specification".

Comment: Thanks for the answer.